# Laravel custom request headers are not populated

Tags: php, laravel

I am using postman to issue requests to my project, Here is what it looks like:

```
Request Headers:
cache-control:"no-cache"
postman-token:"65b35825-8c35-47ae-ad03-159d3da08e95"
partner_key:"123456789"
partner_secret:"123456789"
business_external_id:"123456789"
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/6.4.1"
accept:"*/*"
host:"loyaltybro.local"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
```

I am interested in the 'partner_key', 'partner_secret', 'business_external_id'.

In my code I am logging the headers received like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    $headers = $request->headers->all();
    \Log::info($headers);
    ...
}
```

Here is log output.

```
local.INFO: array (
  'cache-control' => 
  array (
    0 => 'no-cache',
  ),
  'postman-token' => 
  array (
    0 => '65b35825-8c35-47ae-ad03-159d3da08e95',
  ),
  'user-agent' => 
  array (
    0 => 'PostmanRuntime/6.4.1',
  ),
  'accept' => 
  array (
    0 => '*/*',
  ),
  'host' => 
  array (
    0 => 'loyaltybro.local',
  ),
  'accept-encoding' => 
  array (
    0 => 'gzip, deflate',
  ),
  'connection' => 
  array (
    0 => 'keep-alive',
  ),
)
```

There are no  'partner_key', 'partner_secret', 'business_external_id'.

Why are they not being populated?

Comment: I think you have to configure apache for this.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: I am using apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Headers with underscores are dropped by default in both nginx and apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html

> Translation of headers to environment variables is more strict than
>   before to mitigate some possible cross-site-scripting attacks via
>   header injection. Headers containing invalid characters (including
>   underscores) are now silently dropped.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/?highlight=disappearing%20http%20headers#missing-disappearing-http-headers

> If you do not explicitly set underscores_in_headers on;, NGINX will
>   silently drop HTTP headers with underscores (which are perfectly valid
>   according to the HTTP standard). This is done in order to prevent
>   ambiguities when mapping headers to CGI variables as both dashes and
>   underscores are mapped to underscores during that process.

Comment: Ok dropping the underscores worked. But i just tried the `getallheaders()` function and headers with '_' and it returns these headers. if apache drops them how come they are visible there?